# Using parallel in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm new to threading and parallelism. I have this method for a game in C# and need to use parallel iteration. How could I use this on the for loops in the below method?

```
public int[,] GetLegalMoves()
{
    int[,] legalMoves = new int[8, 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            if (IsMoveLegal(i, j)) legalMoves[i, j] = 1;
            else legalMoves[i, j] = 0;

    return legalMoves;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use PLINQ you'll need to use datatypes that implement IEnumerable. A jagged `int` array is not the WTG.

Comment: what do you mean by parallel?, here I see two loops nested

Comment: @Jeremy: that's a 2-dimensional array `[,]` , not a jagged array `[][]`.

Comment: First off, WHY do you need this to be parallel?  Before doing anything else, first profile and find out if this is even worth optimizing any further than what it is.  Also, is the function IsMoveLegal even capable of being executed in parallel?

Comment: @JeremyThompson That's not a jagged array, it's a two dimensional array. Anyways, if your board size is always 8x8 then don't bother implementing PLINQ/threading/anything. That code runs super fast even if that array was 2048x2048. If you really wanted to parallize that, you could flatten that 2D array into 1D array and then use PLINQ with it (however I have never used PLINQ and I don't know how it works, but I assume the way I just described would work)

Comment: BTW - for working with arrays, I would use the `Parallel` class instead of PLINQ.  For details on options for parallelizing, see: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be parallelized by parallelizing your outer loop:

```
public int[,] GetLegalMoves()
{
    int[,] legalMoves = new int[8, 8];

    Parallel.For(0, 8, i =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            if (IsMoveLegal(i, j)) legalMoves[i, j] = 1;
            else legalMoves[i, j] = 0;
    });

    return legalMoves;
}
```

That being said, this will likely cause this to run slower, as an 8x8 matrix is such a small value that the overhead of scheduling the parallel work is likely higher than the gains made, unless `IsMoveLegal` is a fairly expensive operation.

This will also require that `IsMoveLegal` be safe to use from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i was looking for, the 'IsMoveLegal' is thread safe so no problem there.  Perfect thanks!